# Laravel Json read in Controller

Tags: json, laravel, substr

im using Laravel and trying to read a json in a controller to clean 1 specific data... and pass all json to view (this last now is working)

```
$url= 'https://example.com/api;
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $res = $client->get($url);
        $content = (string) $res->getBody();
    
        $customers= json_decode($content, true);

        $firstNumbers = substr($content->numbertotal, 0, 2);

        $latestNumber = substr($string, -1);

        return [$customers, $firstNumbers, $latestNumber];
```

actually im using `data["customer"]["denominacion"]` to display only "name of customer" for example en view...

but i need... in numbertotal... like: 1122222223 recover only the... 11 and the 3 to save it on database after. any can help me?

my json is:

```
{"result":"success","customer":{"nro_evento":2960505,"nro_secuencia_contacto":1,"Tipo_contacto":{"Cod_contacto":1,"Descripcion":null,"Visible":null,"Representante":0},"numbertotal":1122222223,"tipo_doc":0,"Tipo_doc_desc":null,"denominacion":"NOMBRE Y APELLIDO","telefono":0,"celular":0,"proveedor_celular":0,"mail":"","cod_area_tel":"","cod_area_cel":"","HabilitadoImpuestos":true}}
```

I cant call only the "numbertotal" value in a controller...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i added a hidden input with the numbertotal... i make a get in store function... and apply the substr.